# Error while generating tstsuite from commandline

Tags: evosuite

While generating test cases using command line option I am getting the following error.

- EvoSuite
- Going to generate test cases for class: testgeneration.Multiplication
  [MASTER] 14:03:51.716 [main] **ERROR TestGeneration - Not possible to access to clients**. Clients' state: Terminated with exit status 1. Master registry port: 14981
  [MASTER] 14:03:51.803 [main] ERROR SearchStatistics - No statistics has been saved because EvoSuite failed to generate any test case
  [MASTER] 14:03:51.904 [main] ERROR TestGeneration - failed to write statistics data

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if EvoSuite's client process does crash. Why is crashing is hard to tell without further information. Could it be a bug in EvoSuite, or some weird combination of events.

Comment: I am using the command for execution & facing the issue. Please let me know if I need to add any more options in the arguments.  **java -jar evosuite-0.2.0.jar -class com.mycompany.Multiplication -Dtest_dir=D:/testgenerationtool/com.mycompany/evosuite-tests -base_dir=D:\testgenerationtool\com.mycompany -projectCP=D:\testgenerationtool\com.mycompany\bin -evosuiteCP=evosuite-0.2.0.jar;evosuite-standalone-runtime-0.2.0.jar**